# How to add a class to the application scope for a web application

Tags: java, jsf, servlets

Need to add a Java class (named HistoryBean in my project)  to the ServletContext. I do not want to create new instance of the HistoryBean class in the different Servlets that I have inside my project. I want to get it from the ServletContext. Please help me with suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that in a `ServletContextListener`:

```
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent e) {
     e.getServletContext().setAttribute("historyBean", new HistoryBean());
}
```

Register your listener with `@WebListener` or with `<listener>..</listener>` in web.xml.

Comment: Thanks Bozho....I did that. Now I am trying to figure out how to get it from the ServletContext in my Servlets, so that I can use the methods inside the HistoryBean........

Comment: call `ctx.getAttribute("historyBean")`

Answer (score 3):

As you're using JSF, just register it as an application scoped bean.

```
@ManagedBean(eager=true)
@ApplicationScoped
public class HistoryBean {
    // ...
}
```

*(note the `eager=true`, this autoconstructs the bean on webapp's startup without the need to reference it in some view or bean,  you don't need a `ServletContextListener` for this)*

This way it's not only available in JSF context the usual way as `#{historyBean}`, but it's in servlets also available as a servlet context attribute with the managed bean name as key as follows:

```
HistoryBean historyBean = (HistoryBean) getServletContext().getAttribute("historyBean");
```

Comment: That are not JPA annotations. That are JSF annotations.